# ConfigParser is successfully setting new values, but doesn't show up in ini Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, configparser

I'm having some trouble getting config parser module to work. I'm currently in the process of creating a file backup program, but whenever I set the values they don't show up in the .ini file. config.get confirms that it was set correctly, but document_backup.ini is blank.

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('document_backup.ini')
config.set('FTP_Login','Host',input("FTP Host: "))
config.set('FTP_Login','UserName',input("FTP UserName: "))
config.set('FTP_Login','Password',input("FTP Password: "))
config.read('') #To close the file, I think
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modifying the in-memory configuration does not affect the file it was originally read from. You need to write the new configuration back to disk.

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('document_backup.ini')
config.set('FTP_Login','Host',input("FTP Host: "))
config.set('FTP_Login','UserName',input("FTP UserName: "))
config.set('FTP_Login','Password',input("FTP Password: "))
with open("document_backup.ini.new", "w") as fh:
    config.write(fh)
os.rename("document_backup.ini", "document_backup.ini~")
os.rename("document_backup.ini.new", "document_backup.ini")
```

Note that the `configparser` module doesn't provide any way to *edit* an existing configuration file. The new file will produce an equivalent configuration, but may not have the same form as the original.

Answer (score 0):

`config.read('')` doesn't close the file...

Try this, it's working for me:

```
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.add_section("MyApp")
config.set("MyApp", "window_height", self.height())
config.set("MyApp", "window_width", self.width())
configfile = open("/path/to/the/file.ini", 'w')
config.write(configfile)
configfile.close()
```

And reading from it:

```
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read("/path/to/the/file.ini")
self.width = config.getint("MyApp", "window_height")
self.height = config.getint("MyApp", "window_width")
```

it works also with `config.getboolean("MyApp","variable")` or simply `config.get("MyApp","variable")` for string